# React Native use JIT(Just in Time) compilation or interpret JavaScript code on Android?

Tags: javascript, react-native, jit, javascriptcore

According to the React Native documentation when an app runs in IOS it uses the JavaSriptCore engine to run JavaScript code, but does not use JIT.

> ["Note that on iOS, JavaScriptCore does not use JIT due to the absence of writable executable memory in iOS apps."](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/javascript-environment)

But there's nothing about it on Android. I would like to know if in Android JavaScript code is interpreted or JIT compiled.

Answer (score 1):

Technically both. JIT compilation means it does interpretation when executed and optional optimization when it's required (Caching in memory to reuse without re-translation). But iOS doesn't allow this kind of dynamic compilation, that's why the documentation saids.